# How to find a point along an vector at an variable distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, trigonometry

I need to find the value along a vector for a given x coordinate. Like so;

[image]

I know the values of A, B and C. All of these value are variable. I need to calculate X. I know this is possable I just can't remember my trigonometry lessons. 
I'm aware of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466871/find-a-point-along-an-angled-line) but it only finds the mid-point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2)

and co-ordinates of X(x,y) , then:

```
y = ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))x + c .....(1)
```

where c is the y intercept, which in this case is 0.

Comment: i left it out for simplicity's sake as he didnt need to know about the y intercept in the problem above.

Comment: Ah, but while the picture shows (0,0) as A, the question was a completely general one. Your answer as it was written originally was incorrect and misleading for the general case. Fixed now though.

Answer (score 1):

```
  y = ||C-A|| / ||D-A||
  Z = (B - A) * y
```

Where y = length of vector C minus vector A, divided by length of D(unlabeled original length along x axis) minus vector A

Answer (score 1):

For a line through the origin, as you have in the picture, you can use the idea of similar triangles:

```
X_y = B_y * (X_x/B_x)
```

Or, for the numbers shown in the example, X_y = 50, and X=(50,50).

To understand this, similar triangles says:

```
X_y/X_x = B_y/B_x
```

since triangles with similar shapes (ie, that have the same angles), have the same ratios; and the first formula is just solving the second to give X_y.

(If the line isn't through the origin, first subtract A from everything, then calculate X_y as above, then add A to everything.)